# Confused by my attempt to use GetBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript

```
var rect = document.getElementById("object").getBoundingClientRect();
console.log("rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left");

<div id="object"></div>

.object {
background: red;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
top: 200px;
}
```

Super elementary question... I am trying to get the coordinates of #object, but the console returns rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left instead of the actual coordinates of #object. What am I missing?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tCraA/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've logged a static string:

```
console.log("rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left");
```

You meant to write this:

```
console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
```